# Recording DAB “multimedia additional services” data

Tags: audio

Is there a Linux software that can record the “multimedia additional services” data from Digital Audio Broadcast (DAB) that contains the title of the current program or music ?

This data is regularly displayed on the receiver display next to the station title.

Please suggest more appropriate tags if any.

Comment: We do not do recommendations & you have not stated what the receiver is or how you are accessing it. However, if qt-dab does not do what you want, then you may be able to extend it. You'll need a suitable dongle to pick up the signals.

Comment: @Bib I don't think it's true that we don't do recommendations – we do have a [tag for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) . What we don't do in recommendations is "opinions please" or unclear recommendations ("what's the best linux distro", "what is the best game launcher"), or such that don't state sufficient requirements ("I need an editor for specific file types. what can you recommend?"). Doesn't seem to me that applies here, in spirit! **But I fully agree**,we need to know what hardware Juergen has to receive DAB (probably: DAB+, as that name's very German)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, it is about German DAB+. I don't have an USB receiver yet and would buy one that is supported by the software found here.

Comment: @Bib, didn't find any info about recording or “multimedia additional services” on https://github.com/JvanKatwijk/qt-dab.